# routing and searching a db ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to retrieve all the tweets that have a certain hashtag in them. 
At first I add the hashtags in my 2 tables :

```
 def add_hashtags(tweet)
      tweet.content.scan(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/){ |tag|
        @allhashes = Hashtag.all
        @hash = Hashtag.find_by_name(tag[0].strip)
        unless @hash
          @hashtag = Hashtag.new(name: tag[0].strip)
          @hashtag.save
          @hashrel = Hashrelation.new(tweet_id: tweet.id, hashtag_id: @hashtag.id)
          @hashrel.save
        else
          @hashrel = Hashrelation.new(tweet_id: tweet.id, hashtag_id: @hash.id)
          @hashrel.save
        end
      }
    end
```

then I want to route to the show method of tweet controller :

```
get 'tweets/show/(.:format)' => 'tweets#show', as: :hashtag
```

The links in the hashtags are as follows:

```
    def twitify(tweet = '')
      tweet.gsub(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/) do |tag|
        " " + link_to("#{tag.strip}", hashtag_path(tag.strip), {:name => tag.strip})
      end.html_safe
    end
```

And finally the show method of the tweet controller is :

```
  def show
    @hashtag = Hashtag.find_by_name(params[:name])
    @tweet_ids = Hashrelation.find_by_hashtag_id(@hashtag.id)
    @feed_items = Tweet.find_by_id(@tweets_ids.id)
  end
```

When I click on the link I get :

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

which means that params[:name] is either nill or it isn't like the one I have in the DB.

Could you guys help me figure this out ?

The link I see that is called is `'http://localhost:3000/tweets/show/.%23dadawea'` which means I have extra things why would I ?.

Comment: You might want to cut the actual `#` from the address.

Comment: i don't know how to use lookbehind i tried it like this tag.gsub!(tag[0],'') but it doesn't seems to work..

Comment: For others: I've been initially mentioning a lookbehind, then noticed a similar pattern and wiped it from the comment. Then I looked up the docs and found out it's not there.

Comment: it thinks you are trying to set the format with `hashtag_path(tag.strip)` so you have 2 options one is change the route to `tweets/show/:name(.:format)` second is use `hashtag_path(name: tag.strip)`. Right now it thinks you are passing html options to name the link. As D-side suggested as well I would not name the hashtags with `#` included.

Comment: Try this, what you currently have seems horribly long and unreadable. `"#hashtag and a #bunch other #stuff".scan /(?<=#)\p{Alnum}/` You might also want to read through the [`Regexp` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html), there's a lot of helpful information.

Comment: hmmm I do try to remove that # by adding tag[0] = '' but it doesn't do the job it seems. How would I remove # ?

Comment: I've provided a simple example of lookbehind above, run it in `irb` or `pry`.

Comment: it returns the first letter after # I did try it. However my tag is something like #hashtag and if i do tag[0] = '' it should be hashtag but it doesn't become that :(

Comment: `"#hashtag and a #bunch other #stuff".scan /(?<=#)\p{Alnum}+/` There was a typo, missing `+`, sorry =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following

```
def add_hashtags(tweet)
  tweet.content.scan(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/).flatten.each do  |tag|
    hashtag = Hashtag.where(name: tag.strip).first_or_create
    Hashrelation.create(tweet_id: tweet.id, hashtag_id: hashtag.id)
  end
end
```

Then change the twitify method to look like

```
def twitify(tweet = '')
  tweet.gsub(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/) do |tag|
    " " + link_to("#{tag.strip}", hashtag_path(name: tag.strip))
  end.html_safe
end
```

And the show method

```
def show
  @hashtag = Hashtag.find_by_name(params[:name])
  @tweet_ids = Hashrelation.where(hashtag_id: @hashtag.id).pluck(:id)
  @feed_items = Tweet.where(tweet_id: @tweets_ids)
end
```

This should be what you are looking for. Now for whats changing:

- Removed Duplicate logic in the add_hashtags to use create instead.
- `twitify` method is passing name as an html option not a url option so I fixed that. Right now it thinks you want to set the format to the name of the hashtag and name the link the name of the hashtag**
- show method is using find_by which will only return a single result not what you wnat for `tweet_ids` so i changed it to where clause and just grabbed the ids. Then changes `feed_items` to search `Tweet` for all `tweet_id`s in the Array.

To strip the `#` just use `tag.strip[1..-1]`

Comment: undefined method `strip' for ["dupaceaspusala"]:Array  which is found in add_hashtags. Can i add tag[0] which returns me the string instead of an array ? or tag[0] returns the first element of the string?(should be the string)

Comment: o and tag still has # in it after regex so when we call ashtag_path(name: tag.strip) I do get %23 which is # in the url

Comment: #<Hashtag id: 20, name: "dupaceaspusala", created_at: "2014-12-23 15:16:05", updated_at: "2014-12-23 15:16:05"> seems we can use tag[0] it's a string !

Comment: @LucianTarna I altered my example a bit for `add_hashtags` so you don't have to use `tag[0]`.

Comment: I see you used 'flatten' to make an array and then take each string from the array :d very nice . Hope I will learn ruby at least as well as you in the near future :P